# python get class object instance from another python file

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, object, instance

I'm pretty new to python and classes so please excuse me if this is obvious!

I have a class object that I run at start up, however I would like to access that instance of the running class from another .py file

How would I go about this?

here is an example of my code:

```
class testclass(xml):
    instanceobject = 0

    def __new__(cls):
        return super(testclass, cls).__new__(cls, 'xmlfile', dir1, dir2)

    def __init__(self):
        super(testclass, self).__init__()
        testclass.instanceobject = self
        print "print from class init", testclass.instanceobject
```

then from my other .py file, I try do the following:

```
from py1file import testclass

print "print from other py file", testclass.instanceobject
```

and I'm getting the following:

```
print from class init
<py1file.testclass object at 0x22F7FA80>

print from other py file
0
```

Basically I want to call a function from the instance of the running class but I need to pass the instance object so I'm trying to get that so I can pass the instance.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Well, that code seems to have worked. What is the problem?

Comment: it's printing 0 instead of the same print from init class print I done.

Comment: Where are you creating an instance though?

Comment: from a 3rd python file which I run before anything. using `import py1file 
d = py1file.testclass()`